# Show one of the taxonomies always as default

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have custom post type called **staff** that has custom taxonomy called **departments**. I wanted the frontpage of the staff (archive-staff.php) to not show ALL the staff members, but actually the first department (lets say there are 3 departments.)

My archive page starts like this:

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array(
    'post_type' => 'staff',
) );
query_posts( $args );

while (have_posts()): the_post(); // ...
```

I have no clue how to go from here. I also need to display the current departments title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
// Custom taxonomy
$custom_taxonomy = 'department';

// Get the current department
if (!$current_department = $wp_query->query_vars[$custom_taxonomy]) {
    $get_all_departments = get_terms($custom_taxonomy, array(
        'number' => 1
    ));
    $current_department = $get_all_departments[0]->slug;
}

// Get the departments information
$department = get_term_by('slug', $current_department, $custom_taxonomy);
```

So the `$current_department` is the slug of the current taxonomy and `$department` is an array of the current taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tax_slug = 'departments';
$tax_term = 'first-department';
// get taxonomy by slug and term
$tax_args = array( $tax_slug => $tax_term );
// merge your args, with the tax args
$args = array_merge( $args, $tax_args );

// Get term object
$term_title = get_term_by( $tax_term, '', $tax_slug );

// Display Title/Headline
echo "<h2>{$term_title->name}</h2>";
```

Comment: @t31os Why? `$tax_slug` is the key for tax querie args.

Comment: Sorry, read too quick, then really the fix should have been an `$` (missing) and not quotes.. my mistake..

Comment: Thank you for answering, however this didn't work for me at all. The comments didn't explain or refocus as much as needed and there was no additional information in your post :(

Comment: What "post"? Btw: You need to store your `$args` first. Else you can't `array_merge` them... Thas _why_ I've written `// merge YOUR args, with the tax args`